# Finding Runs of Consecutive Ones

Tags: r

I'm from pharmaceutical background.I'm new to coding. I've started reading the book "The art of R programming!" I'm getting the concepts of it by time. Well, I'm stuck on the topic named "Finding Runs of Consecutive Ones." In the particular example There is vector (1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1)from which the number of 1s are to be find. If we want to find consecutive two 1s the code should return the value (4,5,8)
I'm unable to understand the code described in the book.

```
findruns <- function(x,k) {
   n <- length(x)
   runs <- NULL
   for (i in 1:(n-k+1)) {
       if (all(x[i:(i+k-1)]==1)) runs <- c(runs,i)
    }
   return(runs)
   }
```

I have list of questions..
1. What does this x and k mean in the 1st line.
2. Why we need to assign NULL to runs
3. What does line 4 and 5 exactly mean!

PS: I know my questions are way too easy to answer as its from initial part of the book!

Comment: Look into `rle`, e.g. `rle(c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1))`.

Comment: I don't have the book with me right now, but Matloff usually goes over the function and explains the different parts. Many of these functions come back later in the book. I would suggest reading on, and coming back to it later. I'm sure you'll know enough about it then!

Comment: k defines the length of the run segments, so if you are looking for repeats of the length 3 of the number 1, you assign 3 to k. x is the vector you are looking for runs within it. You assign NULL to runs to start with an empty vector as you will be concatenating to it using the c() function as you have on line 5 of the code you provided. During the first iteration you would be concatenating the first find to NULL, now you have something inside runs, after your next "find" you don't want to overwrite what you already have in NULL you concatenate it to it and keep repeating that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could get the index of consecutive tuple of ones, using `stri_locate_all`.  We `paste` the `vector` 'v1' to a single string, and use the regex lookaround (`(?=11)`) to match the pattern.  The `stri_locate_all` gives the 'start' and 'end' index of all those tuples of `11`.  Here I extracted only the `start` column (`[,1]`)

```
library(stringi)
stri_locate_all(paste(v1, collapse=""), regex="(?=11)")[[1]][,1]
#[1] 4 5 8
```

---

Regarding the OP's function, it has two input variables, 'x' and 'k' where 'x' represents the vector ('v1'), 'k' the tuple length which I guess would be 2.  We assign 'n' as the `length` of the vector, create a `NULL` vector 'runs' for allocating the output index.  Then, we loop through the sequence of the vector until the 6th element (`n-k+1`), and for each 'i', we again take the sequence beginning from 'i' to `i+k-1` i.e. if the 'i' is 1, the index will be '2', and the sequence is `1:2`, get the elements in the vector corresponds to that `v1[1:2]`, check whether it is equal to 1, if `all` the elements are 1, then we concatenate the 'runs' with the corresponding index ('i')

#### data

```
 v1 <- c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1)
```

Comment: The question is not really about the best way to find consecutive ones, it's about understanding the code (those eight lines).

Comment: @Axeman Yes, I understand, but the answer is not specific only for the OP.  It is for all those people who visit the SO.  Showing a loopless way to get the output doesn't really hurt anybody.

Comment: @Axeman I added some description about how the OP's code is working.  If you would like to edit, please feel free to do so ..